# Из xml взять нужную информацию в определенном порядке и записать её в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, парсер

Есть файл xml в виде:

```
<item id="31025805">
        <genre>статья в сборнике трудов конференции</genre>
        <type>статья в сборнике трудов конференции</type>
        <source id="31025548">
            <titles>
                <title lang="EN">CEUR Workshop Proceedings</title>
            </titles>
            <titleaddinfo>3</titleaddinfo>
            <volumenumber>1825</volumenumber>
            <volumename>MMIT 2016 - Proceedings of 3rd Russian Conference "Mathematical Modeling and Information Technologies"</volumename>
            <seriesname>MMIT 2016 - Proceedings of 3rd Russian Conference "Mathematical Modeling and Information Technologies"</seriesname>
            <yearpubl>2016</yearpubl>
            <confname>3rd Russian Conference "Mathematical Modeling and Information Technologies", MMIT 2016</confname>
            <confplace>Yekaterinburg</confplace>
            <confdatebegin>16.11.2016</confdatebegin>
        </source>
        <pages>111-117</pages>
        <language>IT</language>
        <yearpubl>2016</yearpubl>
        <cited>0</cited>
        <titles>
            <title lang="EN">Modelling of cash flows by means of Markov processes</title>
        </titles>
        <grnti>270100</grnti>
        <risc>yes</risc>
        <corerisc>yes</corerisc>
        <authors>
            <author num="1" lang="EN">
                <lastname>Timofeeva</lastname>
                <initials>G.A.</initials>
                <authorid>15676</authorid>
                <spin>2292-7833</spin>
                <email>Gtimofeeva@usurt.ru</email>
                <affiliations>
                    <affiliation num="1" lang="EN">
                        <orgname>Ural State University of Railway Transport</orgname>
                        <orgid>6766</orgid>
                        <country>rus</country>
                        <town>Yekaterinburg</town>
                    </affiliation>
                    <affiliation num="2" lang="EN">
                        <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname>
                        <orgid>290</orgid>
                        <country>rus</country>
                        <town>Yekaterinburg</town>
                    </affiliation>
                </affiliations>
            </author>
            <author num="2" lang="EN">
                <lastname>Bozhalkina</lastname>
                <initials>Y.A.</initials>
                <authorid>779136</authorid>
                <spin>6791-5486</spin>
                <email>Bozhalkina@mail.ru</email>
                <affiliations>
                    <affiliation num="1" lang="EN">
                        <orgname>Ural State University of Railway Transport</orgname>
                        <orgid>6766</orgid>
                        <country>rus</country>
                        <town>Yekaterinburg</town>
                    </affiliation>
                </affiliations>
            </author>
        </authors>
    </item>
    <item id="29099767">
        <genre>статья в сборнике трудов конференции</genre>
        <type>статья в сборнике трудов конференции</type>
        <source id="29091999">
            <titles>
                <title lang="EN">Mathematical Modeling and Information Technologies</title>
                <title lang="RU">Математическое моделирование и информационные технологии</title>
            </titles>
            <titleaddinfo>Proceedings</titleaddinfo>
            <yearpubl>2016</yearpubl>
            <pagesnumber>275</pagesnumber>
            <publisher>CEUR-WS.org</publisher>
            <confname>3rd Russian Conference "Mathematical Modeling and Information Technologies"</confname>
            <confplace>Екатеринбург</confplace>
            <confdatebegin>16.11.2016</confdatebegin>
            <confdateend>16.11.2016</confdateend>
        </source>
        <pages>111-117</pages>
        <language>RU</language>
        <yearpubl>2016</yearpubl>
        <cited>0</cited>
        <titles>
            <title lang="RU">Моделирование потоков платежей с помощью марковских случайных процессов</title>
        </titles>
        <grnti>270100</grnti>
        <risc>yes</risc>
        <corerisc>no</corerisc>
        <authors>
            <author num="1" lang="EN">
                <lastname>Timofeeva</lastname>
                <initials>G.A.</initials>
                <authorid>15676</authorid>
                <spin>2292-7833</spin>
                <email>Gtimofeeva@mail.ru</email>
                <affiliations>
                    <affiliation num="1" lang="EN">
                        <orgname>Public Educational Institution of Higher Professional Education The Ural State University of Railway Transport</orgname>
                        <orgid>6766</orgid>
                        <country>RUS</country>
                        <town>Ekaterinburg</town>
                        <address>Kolmogorov Street 66, Ekaterinburg, Russia, 620034</address>
                    </affiliation>
                </affiliations>
            </author>
            <author num="1" lang="RU">
                <lastname>Тимофеева</lastname>
                <initials>Галина Адольфовна</initials>
                <authorid>15676</authorid>
                <spin>2292-7833</spin>
                <email>Gtimofeeva@mail.ru</email>
                <affiliations>
                    <affiliation num="1" lang="RU">
                        <orgname>Уральский государственный университет путей сообщения</orgname>
                        <orgid>6766</orgid>
                        <country>RUS</country>
                        <town>Екатеринбург</town>
                        <address>620034  г.Екатеринбург, ул. Колмогорова,66</address>
                    </affiliation>
                </affiliations>
            </author>
            <author num="2" lang="EN">
                <lastname>Bozhalkina</lastname>
                <initials>Ya.A.</initials>
                <authorid>779136</authorid>
                <spin>6791-5486</spin>
                <email>bozhalkina@mail.ru</email>
                <affiliations>
                    <affiliation num="1" lang="EN">
                        <orgname>Public Educational Institution of Higher Professional Education The Ural State University of Railway Transport</orgname>
                        <orgid>6766</orgid>
                        <country>RUS</country>
                        <town>Ekaterinburg</town>
                        <address>Kolmogorov Street 66, Ekaterinburg, Russia, 620034</address>
                    </affiliation>
                </affiliations>
            </author>
            <author num="2" lang="RU">
                <lastname>Божалкина</lastname>
                <initials>Яна Андреевна</initials>
                <authorid>779136</authorid>
                <spin>6791-5486</spin>
                <email>bozhalkina@mail.ru</email>
                <affiliations>
                    <affiliation num="1" lang="RU">
                        <orgname>Уральский государственный университет путей сообщения</orgname>
                        <orgid>6766</orgid>
                        <country>RUS</country>
                        <town>Екатеринбург</town>
                        <address>620034  г.Екатеринбург, ул. Колмогорова,66</address>
                    </affiliation>
                </affiliations>
            </author>
        </authors>
    </item>
```

Нужно взять данные в определенном порядке: название статьи - авторы, к ней относящиеся. Записать это все в словарь. Например:

```
author_publ = {
'Modelling of cash flows by means of Markov processes': Timofeeva G.A., Bozhalkina Y.A.,
'Математическое моделирование и информационные технологии': Тимофеева Галина Адольфовна, Божалкина Яна Андреевна
}
```

Comment: Чем больше информации, тем лучше. Например, о том, из каких тегов вытаскивать. Кст, я правильно понял, что если есть 2 заголовка, то на русском будет приоритетнее?

Comment: Заголовок у публикации один он в теге <titles> (идет после тега <cited>). Пусть Вас не смущают другие <titles> - это наименование сборника, в котором печаталась статья(их не нужно). Фамилия и имя в тегах: <lastname> и <initials> соответственно

Comment: А если есть несколько названий на разных языках, какой выбрать? Кст, а подскажите откуда эта xml? :)

Comment: Если речь о ФИО, то русский. А наименование статьи в одном экземпляре, если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: Этот файл с моей работы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, сами сможете поместить в словарь:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


text = """
<item id="31025805">
    <genre>статья в сборнике трудов конференции</genre>
...
    </authors>
</item>
"""

def get_title_book(item) -> str:
    titles = item.find_all("titles")[1]
    return titles.title.text


def get_author_full_name(author_node) -> str:
    return author_node.lastname.text + ' ' + author_node.initials.text


def get_authors(item) -> list:
    authors = item.select('authors > author')

    # Словарь для хранения номера автора и списка на разных языках
    num_author_by_authors = dict()

    for author in authors:
        num = author['num']
        if num not in num_author_by_authors:
            num_author_by_authors[num] = []

        num_author_by_authors[num].append(author)

    authors_full_name = []

    for num, authors in num_author_by_authors.items():
        # Тут нечего выбирать
        if len(authors) == 1:
            full_name = get_author_full_name(authors[0])
            authors_full_name.append(full_name)

        else:
            # По умолчанию берем первый элемент
            full_name = get_author_full_name(authors[0])

            for author in authors:
                # Приоритетный язык
                if author['lang'] == "RU":
                    full_name = get_author_full_name(author)
                    break

            authors_full_name.append(full_name)

    return authors_full_name


root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

for item in root.select('item'):
    title_book = get_title_book(item)
    print(title_book)

    authors = get_authors(item)
    print(authors)

    print()
```

Консоль:

```
Modelling of cash flows by means of Markov processes
['Timofeeva G.A.', 'Bozhalkina Y.A.']

Моделирование потоков платежей с помощью марковских случайных процессов
['Тимофеева Галина Адольфовна', 'Божалкина Яна Андреевна']
```

Comment: Супер!!! Все отлично работает!!! Спасибо Вам большое!!!

Comment: Отлично :) Тогда отметьте ответ )